# How do I save a value from an html input field into a database?

Tags: php, html

I know this seems like a very simple problem, but it's been really bothering me for a while. So pretty much, I have an input thing in html, then when the user clicks a button it's supposed to store the information they typed in the box into the database.

I already know the part that sends the info to the database works because I've tried it. But it's not echoing "works!" so its not recognizing any input in the input box.

```
$submit = @$_POST['test'];

$col= "";

$get_info = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT col FROM users WHERE 
username = '$username'");
$get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_info);
$db_col = $get_row['col'];

$col =  @$_POST['coly'];

if($submit){

    if($col){

        echo"works!";
        $update_col = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users SET col 
              = 
            '$col' WHERE username = '$username'");
    }
}

<div class = "profileLeftSideContent">

    <form action = "edit.php" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="coly" size="25" 
                 placeholder="School" 
             /> <br /><br />

    </form>
</div>

<form class="budon" method="POST">

<input  type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="Save"/><br/>

</form>
```

It should be sending the typed information to the database, but instead, it doesn't even echo "worked!" so it thinks that $col has nothing typed in it. It is giving me no errors and the button works fine. Thank you for any input you might have.

Comment: You missed submit button and a closing bracket.
And you better remove error suppression!

Comment: What do you  mean error suppression?

Comment: Sorry not error the warning @

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: The submit button and closing bracket I have, I just forgot to show it here, also I have stuff elsewhere for sql injection but thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's not because `$col` has nothing, it's because `$submit` is empty since the form has no field named 'test' so `$_POST['test']` returns nothing.

```
$submit = $_POST['test'];

$col= "";

$get_info = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT col FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_info);
$db_col = $get_row['col'];

$col =  $_POST['coly'];

if($submit){

    if($col){

        echo"works!";
        $update_col = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users SET col = '$col' WHERE username = '$username'");
    }

}

<div class = "profileLeftSideContent">

    <form action = "edit.php" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="coly" size="25" placeholder="School"/> 
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="test" value="Submit"/>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: I have a button and it works fine, I just didn't show it in the code because it works fine. I added it in now though if you want to see it.

Comment: The button and the input field should be in the same <form> tag. Because they are in different forms, $col will be empty since there is no 'coly' field in the form where the button was submitted.